# How to structure React code which uses DOM rendered in a different framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie with React and jsx.

I have a project where I am using React for the first time, but there are still some parts of the page which are not React-based, they use some other framework. Until that older code is refactored to use React or some agnostic way I will need to use both frameworks for now.

This other framework needs to be lazily included on the page, so it might take some time to load. Once available, I can create an object and call `.placeAt(id)` to tell the object where to render its DOM.

The below code is just a sample of what my current solution looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import loadWidget from './loadWidget'; 

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="app"></div>
  );
}

// loadWidget returns a Promise object which resolves with the Widget class asynchronously
// I need to create a new Widget that will then be placed into the App's <div> using the ID
loadWidget().then(Widget => {
  new Widget().placeAt('app'); // Renders into the div with id "app"
});

export default App;
```

The code above works, but there are some issues with it that make it clear to me that I must not be well adapted to this React programming model yet, where I'm more used to Object oriented programming. In the code above it only works if the `index.js` calls the `App()` function exactly once and it must be called prior to the `loadWidget()` promise having returned. In my case, this is always true since the call to App is synchronous and I know it will only happen once, but I am not satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use other life cycle methods of React. 
From what I can understand you're looking for a way to load them on based on

I believe what you're looking for can be adapted to

`componenetDidUpdate(props)` which will be called every time your `props` or `states` will be called.

So what you can do is use a `State` and then put the updated value in the state for which you need to render the HTML.

So something like this

```
<div> Render some HTML by ${myStateVariable} </div>
```

This would help you render your choice of HTML but there're some implications to it, I would recommend you to first read some materials such as

1. React life cycle components
   [enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
2. States and Props
   [enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: The ${variable} is not really something I can get, it's not like the Widget class has a property on it with a String. The only thing I have is a function `placeAt` where I need to provide an ID for the DIV where the widget should insert it's generated DOM.